# Calling two mutations from the same action

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm using a `Vuex` store to keep all the items in a shopping cart.

There's two actions on the store :

- `getCartContent`, which gets called on page load (fetches the initial content from the backend, which in turn retrieves the data from the session)
- `addToCart`, which is dispatched by the `<Products>` component when the user clicks the *add to cart* button.

Both of these call a respective mutation (with the same name), since you're not supposed to call mutations directly from within components.

Here is what the store looks like :

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
 state: {
  items: [],
 },

 mutations: {
  getCartContent(state, data){
   axios.get('/api/cart').then(response => {
    state.items = response.data;
   });
  },

  addToCart(state, data){
   axios.post('/api/cart/add', {
    item_id: data.item,
   });
  }
 },

 actions: {
  getCartContent(context){
   context.commit('getCartContent');
  },

  addToCart(context, data){
   context.commit('addToCart', {item: data.item});
  }
 }
});
```

This is working as expected, but now when an item is added to the cart (with a dispatch to the `addToCart` action from within the component), I would like it to call the `getCartContent` mutation just after so that it fetches a fresh list of items from the backend.

I tried commiting the second mutation from the same action, like this :

```js
actions: {
    // ...
 
 addToCart(context, data){
  context.commit('addToCart', {item: data.item});
  context.commit('getCartContent');
 }
}
```

But that doesn't always work, sometimes it will fetch the items but not always.

I also tried dispatching the `getCartContent` action from within the component itself, right after dispatching the `addToCart` action, but it's the same problem.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can call `commit` within components, there's no problem with that. Reserve actions for asynchronous code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `axios` calls are asynchronous, meaning that your `addToCart` mutation might not necessarily be finished when your `getCartContent` mutation fires. So, it's not surprising that sometimes `getCartContent` doesn't return the items you told `axios` to send a post request for *immediately* prior.

You should move asynchronous calls to the vuex actions:

```
actions: {
  getCartContent(context, data) {
    axios.get('/api/cart').then(response => {
      state.items = response.data;
      context.commit('getCartContent', response.data), 
    });
  },
  addToCart(context, data) {
    axios.post('/api/cart/add', {
      item_id: data.item,
    }).then(() => {
      context.commit('addToCart', data.item)
    })
  },
}
```

And your mutations should do nothing but make simple, straight-forward changes to the module state:

```
mutations: {
  getCartContent(state, items) {
    state.items = items;
  },
  addToCart(state, item) {
    state.items.push(item);
  }
}
```

---

The above explanation assumes that instead of making a `get('/api/cart')` request after each POST request, you would just keep track of items by pushing the data to the `state.items` property.

If however, you really want to make the GET request after adding an item, you can just get rid of the `addToCart` mutation and `dispatch` the `getCartContent` action after the POST request finishes:

```
addToCart(context, data) {
  axios.post('/api/cart/add', {
    item_id: data.item,
  }).then(() => {
    context.dispatch('getCartContent');
  })
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes a lot of sense. Your edit came just in time, I want to make another call to getCartContent since there's some other things calculated in the backend (ex: total). I'll just re-dispatch the getCartContent action from the addToCart one.